# Using SharedPreference to save an activity in android?

Tags: java, android

I have an app where in the mainActivity the user has about 5 options to choose from. Clicking one of them opens a new activity but essentially all 5 opens up identical activities with different headings. In the newly opened activities, users use multiple rating bars to delegate points to some specified attributes.  Using SharedPreference, can I save the entire activity so when I back out, click on the same option everything isn't gone? Or do I need to save let's say, the individual rating bar values using the SharedPreference?

Here is some code for one of the activities that opens from a button click. Something is terribly wrong because it is crashing now. Any suggestions?

```
public class MageSkillScreen extends AppCompatActivity

{

    public float skillPoints = 10;
    public float strengthRating;
    public float intellectRating;
    public float wisdomRating;
    public float dexterityRating;
    public float totalSkill;


    public float mageStrength;
    public float mageDexterity;
    public float mageIntellect;
    public float mageWisdom;

    public RatingBar strengthBar;
    public RatingBar intellectBar;
    public RatingBar wisdomBar;
    public RatingBar dexterityBar;
    Button submit;

    //preferences
    SharedPreferences magePref;
    boolean rememberRatings = true;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mage_skill_screen);

        strengthBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.mageStregth);
        intellectBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.mageInt);
        wisdomBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.mageWisdom);
        dexterityBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.mageDext);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = magePref.edit();
        edit.putFloat("strengthPts", strengthBar.getRating());
        edit.putFloat("dexterityPts", dexterityBar.getRating());
        edit.putFloat("intellectPts", intellectBar.getRating());
        edit.putFloat("wisdomPts", wisdomBar.getRating());
        //edit.putString("pointsLeft", ptsRemaing.getText().toString());
        edit.commit();

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        rememberRatings = magePref.getBoolean("mageRatings", true);

        mageStrength =  magePref.getFloat("strengthPts", 0.0f);
        mageDexterity = magePref.getFloat("dexterityPts", 0.0f);
        mageIntellect = magePref.getFloat("intellectPts", 0.0f);
        mageWisdom = magePref.getFloat("wisdmPts", 0.0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to save attribute/properties in shared preffernce instaed of saving whole Activity

Comment: please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

update view activity in function onResume

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     //load SharedPreferences again and update view

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's go step by step.

> So I have an app where in the mainActivity the user has about 5
>   options to choose from.

Okay, sounds good, so you have 5 buttons in **MainActivity** for users.

> Clicking one of them opens a new activity but essentially all 5 opens
>   up identical activities with different headings.

Can, you please be more specific here, click on one button should launch one single activity not all 5. And this is not possible at a time only one activity exists for the user to view or interact with. Others, goes in the backstack.
Please read about activity lifecycle for the same.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

> Using SharedPreference, can I save the entire activity so when I back
>   out, click on the same option everything isn't gone?

No, you can't save the whole activity inside **Sharedpreference**. SharedPref is used to store key value pairs, like hashMap and only primitive values, you can store activities and you should never do it.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

**Now, coming back to the solution for the same.**

It totally depends on the usecase you are trying to implement, if you are launching different activities on each button click and want to persist some data across other activities, store the primitive values in sharedpref
and then access it in other activities.This also holds, true if you want to persist the same data in app re-launch.

If not, then you can have a singleton object and modify it and access it, across other activities, make sure to make it null to avoid memory leak.

I hope it clears your doubt.

Cheers..!!

Comment: what I meant is each button opens a new activity. they don't open the same activity. so like button1 opens newActivity1, button2 opens newActivity2 etc. but each "newActivity" essentially has the same layout and will pretty much do the same thing